# C# Extension method for AddItem to IEnumerable<T>

Tags: c#, collections

What is the best way to add an item to IEnumerable collection using Extension method?

Comment: you can't add element to IEnumerable, the best you can is create new IEnumerable with one more element

Comment: Yes, I know that. That is why I ask what is the best way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
enumerable.Concat(new[]{ objToAdd })
```

Comment: actually this is creating new enumerable, not adding to existing one

Comment: Yeah, but since `IEnumerable<T>`  **interface** itself is read-only, that's the only possible way.  Adding to underlying collection is not always an option (e.g. when the underlying collection doesn't really exist).

Comment: To emphasise what `Andrey` commented: It does not **exactly** implement an `AddItem` method (eg. add `item` to the `IEnumerable`) as you would expect it to work. More fitting name for such a method would be `Concat(item)` - there you would expect the method to return a new IEnumerable.

Comment: Well, I will use this method in combination with NHibernate. The collection is a property of an EntityObject and this object controls CRUD operations for the collection. I must try it but I am not sure in what will result this when we create brand new enumerable after adding the new item.

Comment: You will have to do `eo.IEnumProperty = eo.IEnumProperty.AddItem(objToAdd );` which is not good since usually you define an `IEnumerable` property as `get`-only.

Answer (score 1):

You **cannot** (directly). The purpose of the interface is to expose an enumerator.

**Edit**: You would have to convert the IEnumerable to another type (like a `List`) or concatenation to add, which would result not in adding to an existing `IEnumerable`, but concatenating to a new `IEnumerable` instead.

The only option would be to test if the if it implements any of the interfaces usable for adding like IList, ICollection, IDictionary, ILookup, ... and even then you won't be sure that you can add to an existing `IEnumerable`.

Comment: And its implemented by enumerable (pun intended) classes which you *can* add to.

Comment: It's not *necessary* that an `IEnumerable` implementation can be added to.  If it were, there would exist `IEnumerable.Add`.  The comment is absolutely correct.

Answer (score 0):

I have this in my IEnumerableExtensions class, not sure its too efficient, but I use it *very* sparingly.

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Add<T>(this IEnumerable<T> enumerable, T item)
{
   var list = enumerable.ToList();
   list.Add(item);
   return list;
}
```

Comment: not good, this allocates additional memory. Mehrdad Afshari's answer is really better.

Comment: Agree totally, which is why this is mostly unused and deprecated in my exytensions library.